# Deleting file which was uploaded with $request->file->store

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

For some reason I am not able to delete a file I upload with $request->file->store.

I tried `\File::delete`, `\File::Delete`, `\Storage::Delete`, and `\Storage::delete`. I want to avoid using `unlink` as that is not the laravel way.

May you please help me?

This is my code:

```
            if ($user->avatar_path) {
                // delete old one
                \File::delete(app_path().$avatar_path);
            }
            $avatar_path = $request->file('avatar')->store('uploads/users/'.$user->id.'/avatar', 'public');


    $user->update($request->except('avatar') + ['avatar_path' => $avatar_path]);
```

We see here that I check if there is an old avatar, and then I want to delete it. Then I upload the next one and update the database with the new path.

Comment: what error are you getting while using `File::delete()`

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Pyramid - I am getting no error. It just continues without error and without deleting. :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this. I had to use `Storage::disk('public')->delete($old_avatar_path);`. Final code:

```
        if ($request->has('avatar')) {
            $old_avatar_path = $user->avatar_path;

            $avatar_path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 'public');
            $user->update($request->except('avatar') + ['avatar_path' => $avatar_path]);

            if ($old_avatar_path) {
                // delete old one
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($old_avatar_path);
            }
```